# Listing python object methods

Tags: python, object

I am Java developer who tries to learn Python for fun.
I have one class Person:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, age, name):
        self.age = age
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
```

Now, I want to work with objects of type Person in another class:

```
class Test:

    def test(self, person):
        name = person.getName2()
```

Without explicitly specifying that person is Person (as in Java) my PyCharm does not list me all possible methods of person. This is very confusing for me, especially when I use another objects I am not familiar with and I want to see all possible methods of it.
Here I can call any method of person (like non-existing getName2()) and that is fine.

My question is how to easily list all possible methods. 
Also, if I pass two different objects as parameters of method test, both having method getName2() but one returning int other string, this will be perfectly fine and it will only fail at runtime, when for example I treat the name as either string or int.

Comment: You can use type-annotations for Pycharm to be able to provide better code-completion. As an aside, in Python, don't write getters and setters.

Comment: If you use Python3, you can use type annotations: `def test(self, person: Person):`. Pycharm's code complatetion will then list fields, methods, etc.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html

Comment: Note that all the issues you mention are due to the fact that Python is a dynamically typed language, unlike Java. As mentioned, modern Python versions and tools allow for "type hints" that assist you, but they do _not_ actually enforce anything. Type unsafety is inherent to dynamic languages, hence ideas like [duck typing](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-duck-typing) or [forgiveness/permission](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175655/python-forgiveness-vs-permission-and-duck-typing).

Comment: Nice! Thank you all. This "type hint" is exactly what I was looking for and unaware of. Do you think it will be bad practice if I explicitly specify the type every time: like a: int = 1 (its obvious that its int, but I will feel better if I specify it)